# strchr function keep giving me core dumped error

Tags: c, strchr

I am trying to write code that copy and print the word in text file on the screen with getline() and strchr() functions.
so this is my code:

```
void read_teams(char* text)
{
    FILE *fp=fopen(text,"r");
    char* tname=NULL;
    size_t tname_size=0;
    while(getline(&tname,&tname_size,fp)!=EOF)
    {
        tname[strchr(tname,'\n')-tname]='\0';
        printf("%s\n",tname);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

when it is read strchr function it's show:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

so why?
i have to use this function  with getline ,so don't tell me to write my code in other way please.

Comment: you need to de allocate (free the buffer) that getline allocated for you! even if the program fails. adding to @user3121023, where is the free call in your code ?

Comment: If the buffer does not contain a `\t` tab character, then `strchr()-tname` will be way before `tname`. That will cause a seg fault.

Comment: Always check if `fopen` succeeds. There is absolutely no excuse for not doing it. And how do you know that `strchr` is the culprit?

Comment: thank you guys it is sloved

Comment: @RayanFarhat where is `'\t'` in the question?  The question and answer do not make sense together.  DV until fixed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica my text file does not contain a '\t', and i am tried the code below and its works

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i am realy dont know but when i change it,its sloved,ask the other mate who called paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the buffer does not contain a `\n` character, then `strchr()-tname` will be way before `tname`. That will cause a seg fault. So use:

```
while(getline(&tname,&tname_size,fp)!=EOF)
{
    char *p= strchr(tname,'\n');
    if (p)
        tname[p-tname]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",tname);
}
```

Comment: Why does this answer talk about `'\t'` when it is not in the question?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, yep. Fixed it.